# .NET Framework 4.8 installation on Windows Docker image servercore:ltsc2019

Tags: docker, dockerfile, .net-4.8

I'm trying to build a docker image with `.NET Framework 4.8`.

The Docker Windows image that I'm using is `servercore:ltsc2019` (it has `.NET Framework 4.7.2` preinstalled).

I've tried using:

- `ndp48-x86-x64-allos-enu.exe`
- `chocolatey netfx-4.8-devpack`

In every case, it gives the error `3010`, which means it requires restart.

Suppressing error is failing docker build with error:

```bash
Encountered an error during Shutdown: failure in a Windows system call: The interface is unknown. (0x6b5)
```

or it's building with a broken `.NET` Framework installation.

What should be my approach here to update `.NET Framework` to `4.8`?

Answer (score 1):

I deduce that you have something which needs both 4.7.2 and 4.8?
Have you tried to do it the other way around?

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
ADD http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=863265 /ndp472-kb4054530-x86-x64-allos-enu.exe
RUN C:\ndp472-kb4054530-x86-x64-allos-enu.exe /quiet /install
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It worked for me, but I've just used the image it self with this:

RUN powershell -Command \
    Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; \
    [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; \
    iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))